# Can you make an optional model attribute required for a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to make a attribute required just for a particular form?

The field is nullable in the model, and there is no validation setup for it currently and I want to keep it that way.

But on 1 form, I would like to make the field required.

Is this possible without creating a separate model for this?

Comment: what about a conditional validation on the model? or strictly you don't want to touch the model?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ActionController`s `require` for the used parameters, something like this:

```
def person_params
  params.require(:person).permit(:name).tap do |person_params|
    person_params.require(:name) # SAFER
  end 
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-require

Does that help you?

Comment: @Blankman could you please accept this answer or let me know if it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I know that you doesn't want to touch the model, but you can do a conditional validation like this that isn't invasive

```
validates_presence_of :your_attribute, :if => :from_specific_form?
```

and create some methods that work with this

```
private

def from_form
  @from_specific_form = true
end

def from_specific_form?
  @from_specific_form
end
```

Then when you want the validation to work, just do something like this

```
xyz = YourModel.new
xyz.from_form
```